# Is it possible in silverlight to change the Required Data Annotations dynamically

Tags: silverlight, data-annotations

Suppose I have 3 fields on a Silverlight based xaml page

Color, Size and SurpriseMe

where none of the fields are required and SurpriseMe is a checkbox initially set to checked.

I want to create the following behavior:

- When SurpriseMe is cleared,

  1. Display the required field data annotations for Color and Size
  2. Enforce the required Validation
- When SurpriseMe is checked,

  1. Remove the required field data annotation
  2. remove the restriction

Is there any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide custom validation (see [`CustomValidationAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.customvalidationattribute%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)). You can roll your own or use a library like [Fluent Validation](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/).

Comment: I looked at that, and can see how to enforce the validation;  But how does that get the required indicator [*] to display

Comment: @Noah: There are various ways to tie FluentValidation into your UI. You can use the `CustomValidationAttribute` from Silverlight's data annotations, or you can use FluentValidation's `ValidatorAttribute`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a custom validation.